# How to write package.json to use Electron with TypeScript, React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

I want to start index.tsx on desktop application.

I set the working folder as follows using create-react-app.

```
$ create-react-app myapp --typescript
```

After that, I installed Electron and wrote src/main.ts. When I ran "npm start", index.tsx started on Browser.

I fixed package.json.

npm start "react-scripts start"-> "electron ."

main "main.ts"

I ran "npm start" and "Error launching app" is displayed.
So I fixed it again.

npm start "electron . " -> "electron src/main.ts"

But "A javascript error occurred in the main process" is displayed.

Maybe main.ts is wrong?

```js
import { app, BrowserWindow, App } from "electron";

class Main {
    private mainWindow: BrowserWindow | null = null;
    private app: App;
    private mainURL: string = `file://${__dirname}/index.html`;

    public constructor(app: App) {
        this.app = app;
        this.app.on("window-all-closed", this.onWindowAllClosed.bind(this));
        this.app.on("ready", this.create.bind(this));
        this.app.on("activate", this.onActivated.bind(this));
    }

    private onWindowAllClosed() {
        this.app.quit();
    }

    private create() {
        this.mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 800,
            height: 400,
            minWidth: 500,
            minHeight: 200,
            acceptFirstMouse: true,
            titleBarStyle: "hidden"
        });

        this.mainWindow.loadURL(this.mainURL);

        this.mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
            this.mainWindow = null;
        });
    }

    private onActivated() {
        if (this.mainWindow === null) {
            this.create();
        }
    }
}

const MyApp: Main = new Main(app);
```

How do I write package.json? I do not want to "npm run eject".